# Implement Scroll Up/Down Functionality using Ralyxa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alexa-skills-kit

I am using [Ralyxa](https://github.com/sjmog/ralyxa) to built alexa skill.

I have been able to develop the skill for voice only device but finding it difficult to implement the same in multi-modal devices using the above gem.

I have used cards to display the text on the screen but the how to implement Scroll Up and Down functionality or Page Up and Down etc that are specifically to view enabled devices.

Answer (score 0):

For all Ruby developers out there wanting to implement multi modal services (scroll up/down, Page up/down etc) in ruby using the above mentioned gem, let me tell you that this gem does not provide this functionality as of now.

So a workaround which I found out was passing custom response for implementing display directives for each request as a response and it worked.

**Note**
: It is just a workaround for those who doesn't have the time to switch to Node or AWS Lambda. Otherwise the best way forward is to implement the same functionality using node ask sdk.